# how to remove all script word from string using existing regex

Tags: java, regex

In my java application, we are using existing regex as below:

Regex = `</*|[^\w\p{L} !#$%&'+,./:=?@|-]|&#|^'|'$|\W'|'[^\w\s]|script:`

The above regex removes the character from script tag i.e. <>() but I want to remove the whole script tag along with word "script".

Input String:

```
<script>alert("asdf")</script>
```

Output String :

```
scriptalertasdfscript
```

Expected Output String :

```
blank
```

Please help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: But I want to update the existing regex which I have provides

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

`<script[^>]*>.*?<\/script>`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dMmWtv/1/)**

Comment: Is it possible to add this in the regex which I have provided?

Comment: Try to update your original regex adding the new one at the beggining, for example: `<script[^>]*>.*?<\/script>|</*|[^\w\p{L} !#$%&'+,./:=?@|-]|&#|^'|'$|\W'|'[^\w\s]|script:`